# How to get cursor position in rich:editor richfaces by javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, rich-text-editor

I have a rich:editor

```
<rich:editor id="editor" width="1000" height="300"
             value="#{emailTemplateHome.instance.emailTemplateContent}"          
             theme="advanced">
</rich:editor>
```

and javascript function

```
function change(){
            var val = document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('editor')}");
            if(val != null){    
                var component = val.component;
                var content = component.tinyMCE_editor.getContent();                
                var position = content.slice(0, val.positionedOffset).length;
                var result = content.substr(0,position) + "{chuc_vu}" + content.substr(position);
                component.tinyMCE_editor.setContent(result);    
            }
        }
```

but `var position` is not defined.

How can i get position of current cursor ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to insert things at the current position you can use this:

```
component.tinyMCE_editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "insert text");
```

If you want to do something with the cursor position that's going to be tricky, since the position in the editor doesn't correspond to the position in the content (the content has HTML tags in it). You can get the position this way:

```
component.tinyMCE_editor.selection.getBookmark().start
```

`val.positionedOffset` is a function that returns an array, I'm not sure what you were using that for (not to mention that `slice(0,x).length` = x)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I just want insert text at the current position and it's ok. But i want insert text "#{chuc_vu}" so it's empty text. With text "{chuc_vu}" so it's working. What's problem with character "#" ???

Comment: You want to insert a bean value? That will not work.

Comment: No. It's just a text. It's look like bean value. Can't It recognize that text ?

Comment: I can insert `"#{some text}"` just fine, what does it look like when you insert it?

Comment: It show empty text. I debug by firebug (on firefox) i see that.

Comment: And if you check the content with `getContent()`?

Comment: It's empty too. I see that "#{text}" change to "" when it jump to function javascipt (not change in function).

Answer (score 0):

Writing something after cursor position:

```
function writeAfterCursor(element) {
                    var bm =tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark().start;
                    var content= tinyMCE.activeEditor
                    .getContent();
                    content= strip(content);
                    var res = content.split("");

                    var res1= []; 
                    var res2= []; 
                    for(i=0; i < bm; i++){
                        res1[i]=res[i];
                    }
                    var j=0;
                    for(i=bm; i < res.length; i++){
                        res2[j]=res[i];
                        j++;
                    }
                    var content1= res1.join("");
                    var content2= res2.join("");
                    content = content1+ element.value+content2;
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(bm);

                }
                function strip(html)
                {
                   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
                   tmp.innerHTML = html;
                   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
                }
```